# Routing system: pass email in parameters

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I need my app execute a function when the URL looks like this

```
domain.com/mobile/#email_confirmed/email@address.com/otherparam
```

I added this route to one of my controller:

```
'email_confirmed/:email/:first': 'emailConfirmed'
```

as well as this function:

```
emailConfirmed: function (email, first)
```

But the function never gets called... However if I change go to this url :

```
domain.com/mobile/#email_confirmed/emailaddresscom/otherparam
```

then it works fine. I guess the problem comes from the at symbol and the dots in the email address. Therefore, I was wondering if there is another way of declaring the route so that it accepts email address.

Comment: [Routes params not working with some characters](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?179882-Routes-params-not-working-with-some-characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with is to set up the route like this:

```
'email_confirmed/.*': 'emailConfirmed'
```

And then I retrieve the params like this in emailConfirmed:

```
var hash = window.location.hash.split('/');
hash.shift();
// hash[0] => email
// hash[1] => first
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice question,

There are a couple hoops you have to jump through to do this, firstly you need to encode or parse in your '@' symbol. Do this either by encoding to %40 OR by passing additional parameters. For example `/myemail%40gmail/com/first` OR `/myemail/gmail/com/first`, then create `function(usernamedomain, tlDomain, first)` OR `function(username, domain, tlDomain, first)` respectively. Then inside function decode the %40 OR parse together the address.

The other way I could see you solving this would include bypassing the routing system altogether. Instead of creating a link for your user to interact with create a Sencha Component that will fire an event you can listen for (list, button etc..), then inside your controller you can either use the data inside a function in that controller or call another controller function using `this.getApplication().getController('SomeOtherController').handleEmail(email, first);`

I have not tried it but with the last option you should not have to encode your url at all.

Again, nice question. Let me know if there are some other specifics,

Good luck, Brad

Comment: The first solution cannot work since the email address can contain an unknown number of dots in the first part of the address. Therefore there is not just one url scheme possible. Second solution is not possible since the use case would be "the user receives an email containing a link to confirm his email address".

Comment: How will your users be calling this url?

Comment: They click a link in an email.